# What is this and why did it fall out of my engine bay?

Tags: vauxhall

I have had a few problems with my car this past month or so and this morning I heard something fall out of the engine bay. Can anyone identify what it is? It looks like the bracket that secures the battery, but that is still intact. It came off the right side of the car. It wasn't hot when I touched it (after driving for an hour) and it seems to have torn off. The car is a Vauxhall/Opel Astra Turbo Coupe.

[image]

Comment: I cannot tell you for sure, but it appears to be a bracket to hold the radiator in place. One thing which seems weird to me is I'd expect to see some type of marring or galling around the hole. This would be from the head of a bolt. This piece doesn't even look like it's been used like this. I'm wondering if it actually fell out of your car or if it is something which has been picked up over time somehow (some type of road debris) which doesn't even belong to your car? Is it painted the same color as your car?

Comment: I suspect that blue dot was put there after some sort of inspection. Probably because there was a missing bolt ;) No, my car is a metallic grey (moonland 3ku to be specific). The last thing I need is a wobbly radiator.